# getting pagination to work

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I am working on a MVC codeigniter based project. My current setup is such that it displays at max 10 tables in a page as per the following query ( ../models/mode.php)

```
 $function getlist($time) 
   {
  $query = $this->db->query('select * from (select job, username,test from jobs  by    time desc  limit 10 ) as a order by time desc');
 .....
 }
```

The query works fine and displays 10 tables in the page. Although the database has more than 10 entries and I want to put 10 table in each page and incorporate pagination so that I can see all 100 results in 10 different pages.

In controller, I have a piece where in I am trying to use pagination library but of no help.

```
            $this->load->library('pagination');
            $config['base_url']= 'http://localhost/pc/index.php/proj/submit/';
            $config['uri_segment'] =5;
            $config['total_rows']= 100;
            $config['per_page'] = 10;

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

All it does is just create the links but doesnt let me traverse through different pages ( ofcourse it will as the controller doesnt know about it). I think limit needs to have a start and end value say 0,100 or start, finish but how can I let controller know about the same. Any feedback/suggestion ? I am new to the MVC world as well as php/mysql.

Comment: Looks like you're not using the 5th segment, but the 3rd. Why that `$config['uri_segment'] = 5` ?

Comment: because the base url is such that there are 5 segments bfeore that ( localhost, pc,index.php, proj and submit)? any flaw with that? Thats what I concluded from `http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html`

Comment: Not at all, those are not segments!! segments are the bits after `index.php`, so `proj/submit` are segments 1 and 2

Comment: aha, in that case I presume the uri_segment will be 3.

Answer (score 0):

You must handle the pagination in your model :

```
$function getlist($time, $start, $limit) 
{
  $query = $this->db->query('select * from (select job, username,test from jobs  by    time desc  limit 10 ) as a order by time desc limit '. $limit .', '. $start);
 .....
}
```

And in your controller :

```
// Get pagination page    
$page = ($this->uri->segment(5))? $this->uri->segment(5) : 0;

$data = $this->mode_model->getlist($time, $config["per_page"], $page);
```

Comment: and where is $limit and $start defined.

Comment: BTW with above edits, now the page doesn't seem to display anything.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$config['uri_segment'] =3;
```

Comment: This may resolve the problem but it would be much more useful if it explained what it does and why it is an answer to the question.

Comment: `uri_segment` is just to have the functionality of pagination in which segment of URL.As mentioned in my previous comment.